# Do last minute IRA contributions reduce taxes on dividends and interest paid during that tax year?

Tags: united-states, taxes, roth-ira

Suppose I contribute to an IRA before the 2013 tax filing deadline in April 2014. I fund the account by moving some securities from an investment account to the IRA account.  These securities paid interest and dividends throughout 2013. Do I get any tax reduction on the interest and dividends paid by these securities in 2013 before I put them in an IRA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot fund an IRA with securities — you can only contribute cash to the IRA. This renders your question moot.